# Is there a tool that allows me to plot a specified distance along a Google Maps route?

Tags: google-maps

I would like to do a virtual walk along a long-distance route that I have plotted in Google Maps. By virtual I mean I will be walking locally and mapping my distance onto the route. So if I walk 10km one day, and 20km the next, I’d like to say to google “show me the point along this route which is 30km along” to see where I have (virtually) reached.

I am aware of the distance measurement tool but that’s not what I’m looking for - that’s for straight-line distance.

I’m not completely tied to using Google Maps for this, so if there is another mapping tool that does this, I’m amenable to switching, although I’ve got the route already defined in Google so I’d rather use that.

Answer (score 4):

Yes. I use [Gmaps Pedometer](https://www.gmap-pedometer.com/) for working out runs / walks, or to see how far I went on day x.  It's not flashy and has been around for ages, but it does the job!

Comment: This seems to be a live route logger with GPS as the input, and I can’t see a way to to allow entry of either distance or route.

Comment: @jl6:  Click the "start route" button, and then double-click at successive waypoints along the route to create a route.  If you turn on "Mile Markers" the software will place markers at the 1-mile, 2-mile, etc. points as you extend the route.  There is an option near the top of the input pane that allows you to switch to km instead.